# Display result related to id and categorise based on roles - Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have two table chairman and members.

Chairman Table

```
id | first_name | from | to | row_status 

-----------------------------------------
1 | old Chairman | 3-2017 | 5-2018 | 0
2 | Chairman | 6-2018 | 4-2018 | 1
```

Members Table

```
id | chairman_id | | Name | role | row_status

-------------------------------------------
1 |  1 | president | P | 0
2 |  1 | vice president | VP | 0
3 |  2 | president | p | 1
4 |  2 | vice president | VP | 1
```

I am trying to show the active(row_Status = 1 ) chairman and members based on the from - to period of chairman ,

I am not sure how to show display the results if there are multiple chairmen.

I am currently displaying the results now as below,

Blade page

```
    @foreach ($statechairmans as $statechairman)
        <li>
            {{$statechairman -> first_name}}
        </li>

        <li> {{ $statechairman->statemembers->first_name }} </li>
    @endforeach
```

Model:

```
State Chairman 
  public function statemembers(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Statemembers', 'id','chairman_id');
    }

State Members

public function statechairman(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Statechairman');
    }
```

I am able to view the result as expected but I am not sure how to handle the data based on the role.

How do I display the users based on their roles and access multiple chairman in case if there are more.,

eg,

```
Active
Chairman -> President -> Vice-President -> etc,

Old Chairman - 3-2017 | 5-2018
Chairman -> President -> Vice-President -> etc,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach ($statechairmans as $statechairman)
        <li>
            {{$statechairman -> first_name}}
        </li>

        <li> {{ $statechairman->statemembers->first_name }} </li>
        @if($statechairman->row_status == 1)
             from : {{ $statechairman->from}}
             to:  {{ $statechairman->to}}
        @endif
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks @Maulik, With the above answer as base, I added the roles too, 

 **at if($statechairman->statemembers->designation_id == 'VP' )
      Role: {{ $statechairman->statemembers->first_name }}
  at endif **